# i want to group items with same name and count value also to place it in viewbag as one with total count

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

![i want to group item with same name in the view and count them][1]

```
2   1   Mouse   GRC-85044   1   0   1   2018-06-28 13:57:39.657 <Binary data>   NULL
3   1   Laptop  GRC-09821   2   0   1   2018-06-28 15:38:53.150 <Binary data>   NULL
4   2   Zebra P4T   GRC-77172   1   0   1   2018-06-29 08:18:20.743 <Binary data>   NULL
5   2   A4/A5 Colour Printer    GRC-09243   2   0   1   2018-06-29 08:19:15.620 <Binary data>   NULL
6   3   Hand Gloves GRC-24963   2   0   1   2018-06-29 08:20:08.077 <Binary data>   NULL
7   4   Test-Tube Holder (Big)  GRC-13199   1   0   1   2018-06-29 08:21:08.857 <Binary data>   NULL
8   4   Medical Glove   GRC-22715   1   0   1   2018-06-29 08:21:53.303 <Binary data>   NULL
9   3   Field Gloves    GRC-23547   2   0   1   2018-06-29 08:22:42.710 <Binary data>   NULL
10  3   Nose Cover  GRC-55003   2   0   1   2018-06-29 08:24:16.383 <Binary data>   NULL
11  1   Keyboard    GRC-79451   1   0   1   2018-06-29 08:37:12.937 <Binary data>   NULL
12  1   Keyboard    GRC-29799   1   0   1   2018-06-29 08:38:08.880 <Binary data>   NULL
13  4   Test-Tube Holder (Big)  GRC-82984   1   0   1   2018-06-29 08:42:53.033 <Binary data>   NULL
14  4   Test-Tube Holder(small) GRC-72426   2   0   1   2018-06-29 08:43:24.757 <Binary data>   NULL
15  3   Medical Glove   GRC-43007   2   0   1   2018-06-29 08:49:16.367 <Binary data>   NULL
16  2   A4/A5 Colour Printer    GRC-68434   1   0   1   2018-06-29 08:50:22.363 <Binary data>   NULL
17  5   Samung A10  GRC-40503   5   0   1   2018-06-29 09:01:55.550 <Binary data>   NULL
18  5   Samung A10  GRC-12560   3   0   1   2018-06-29 09:02:53.657 <Binary data>   NULL
19  1   Getac S4    GRC-53087   1   0   1   2018-06-29 09:03:51.423 <Binary data>   NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

i want to group items with same name and ID together and count number of each available
have tried :

```
var d = from r in data group r by r.CatagorieId into g select g;
ViewBag.d = d.Count();

IEnumerable<Item> data = db.Items;
```

Comment: Please format your question, this is an unreadable mess right now.

Comment: i mean i have a list of items with same name and i want to group each having same name and count it different instead of listing the item   one by one on the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items.GroupBy(i => i.Name)
     .Select(g => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(g.Key, g.Count()))
```

Comment: Thanks Very Helpful